# HTML Change text when pressed not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a social media website, and I am adding a functionality where if the summary of a post is greater than 50 characters, show the summary up to 50 characters. If this is also the case, I append a **..more** at the end of the summary, and when that is pressed, for now change the text to an empty string.

On the feed page, the most recent post works perfectly, then the ones further down that have **...more** appended don't change when pressed.

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load static %}
{% for post in posts %}
<script>
    function moretext(){
      document.getElementById("moretext").innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
  <div class="container pl-5">
    <div class="row pt-3">
      <img src="{% static 'rect.jpg' %}" width="600px" height="60px">
      <div class="pt-3 pl-5" style="position: absolute;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> </div>
      <br>
      <div class="card" style="width: 600px;">
         <img src="{{ post.file.url }}" width="599px">
      </div>
      <br>
      <img src="{% static 'rect.jpg' %}" width="600px" height="150px">
      <div class="col-6">
          {% if post.summary|length > 50 %}
              <div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 75px; left: 35px;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> {{ post.summary_pretty }} <span onclick="moretext()" id="moretext" style="cursor: pointer;" class="text-muted">...more</span> </div>
          {% else %}
              <div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 75px; left: 35px;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> {{ post.summary }}  </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def summary_pretty(self):
        return self.summary[:50]

    def summary_rem(self):
        return self.summary[50:]
```

Related:

```
   <script>
           function addMore(e) {
              e.innerText = "{{ post.summary_rem }}";
            }
        </script>

<span onclick="addMore(this)" style="cursor: pointer;" class="text-muted">...more</span>
```

Comment: you need to share the HTML for someone to spot possible issues.

Comment: Hey I have added the HTML that could have possible issues inside.

Comment: try giving the `<script>` logic after your div please

Comment: I have added the <script> logic into the div, however the same issue occurs. I think that the id my span has is being called by multiple posts. Is this allowed in html? or should I attempt to create a unique id for the span for every post

Comment: nope, ID should be unique, if this is a loop, then for sure, that is the error

Comment: At the top of the HTML document is a for loop is displayed to loop through the posts. The span tag has an id tag. Can you suggest a way to make that id unique for each time the posts are looped through?

Comment: do you need the solution in pure JS or jQuery?

Comment: pure js is what's required

Comment: It's part of the project criteria that this certain functionality requires pure javascript.

Comment: yep, have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use the `this` associated with onclick event. The `this` will allow you to access the element and you can apply your logic.

```js
function addMore(e) {
  e.innerText = "New conent added " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  e.className += ' hasconent';
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.post {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.more {
  color: blue;
}

.more:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.more.hasconent {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  <span class="more" onclick="addMore(this)">More..</span>
</div>
<div class="post">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  <span class="more" onclick="addMore(this)">More..</span>
</div>
<div class="post">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  <span class="more" onclick="addMore(this)">More..</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, there is a slight problem. I have a function on my Post model which displays the summary of a post after 50 characters. This is called summary_rem, and can be seen on my original post. I use {{ post.summary_rem }} in the javascript, however the summary of a random post is being shown.

Comment: can you please raise it as a different issue? or do you think it is related to the post?

Comment: I believe it is related, as the python side is spot on accurate. This issue is within the html

Comment: can you elaborate? the html part here gives you the correct element to insert content, the actual content needs to be from the logic you implement.

Comment: Yep, I have added the logic at the end of the original post.

Comment: I have figured out the issue. It's within the html, as when i change the logic inside <script> tags it displays the property of a certain post (One at the end of the feed). When I do {{ post.user.username }} for example it displays the username of the wrong user.

Comment: it that's the case, I don't think HTML is to be blamed.

Comment: It is, as I checked all of the python and everything is spot on. I even looped through posts and displayed every posts username. Weirdly that worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using multiple instances of the same ID for different posts. You can only have 1 ID.

Comment: So that the functionality can work for multiple posts

Comment: In the script tag, instead of summary_pretty, it should be summary_rem. Have just update, sorry my mistake.